# Скачок в функции slideToggle

Tags: jquery

Использую slideToggle в выпадающем подменю. Оно открывается плавно, но почти в самом конце анимации происходит рывок. Я пытался это гуглить и исправлять - сперва нашёл проблему с тем, что анимация может подлагивать из-за padding и margin отступов. Убрал их, перенёс пункты подменю на height и line-height. Анимация стала плавнее, но рывок остался. Потом нагуглил, что проблема связана с адаптивной шириной(% вместо px). Пытался и эту проблему решить путём вычисления ширины окна браузера и присвоения фиксированной ширины через .css(). И это тоже не помогло. Как решить проблему рывка?

Comment: добавь код пожалуйста как сделал или же на codepen.io залей

Comment: @FrankSinatra заливать большой кусок кода не очень удобно. Откройте [ссылку](https://jamesjgoodwin.ru/orders/skytickets/) и сделайте зум страницы до тех пор, пока не появится мобильная версия. В мобильной версии откройте меню, а внутри него подменю(любой пункт меню). Там и будет виден рывок.

Comment: попробуй дать menu.slideToggle(400);

Comment: @FrankSinatra то же самое. Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: .dropdown-list {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    background: transparent;
    padding-top: 20px;
    transform: translateY(-1em);
    /* transition: all 0.3s ease-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.1s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s; */
}  удали Этот транзишин

Comment: и все будет гуд

Comment: @FrankSinatra спасибо большое за помощь! Перепишите комментарий в форму ответа. Помечу, как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.menu-item-list li .dropdown-list{
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  background: #eeeeee;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  padding-top: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(0em);
  transition: none;
}
```

На мобильной версии добавь и все будет гуд